# Creating new option (add_option) from AJAX - Settings API

Tags: plugins, php, ajax

I am making a plugin and need to insert a value using the '[add_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/)' function - or something that achieves the same result.

This is what I use to call my AJAX:

```
// localize script
wp_localize_script('button-js', 'the_ajax_script', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

And what launches the PHP function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_process_form', array($this, 'process_ajax'));
```

I need to run add_option() in the function called *after* my AJAX runs (my AJAX code below):

```
function post(num) {

    var data = {
        action : 'process_form',
        form_number : num   
    };

    $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data).error(
        function() {
            alert('error');
        }).success(function() {
            console.log(data);
        });

        return false;
}
```

And here is the function that is run by AJAX:

```
public function process_ajax() {
    $num = $_POST['form_number'];

    if(isset($num)) {
        add_option('form-num', $num); 
    }

    die();

}
```

My AJAX code runs successfully, and the correct values are logged to the console - however upon using

```
<?php echo get_option('form_num'); ?>
```

The value is blank.

Comment: have you inspected the return from add_option() or looked at the database itself, to see that the option key/value is actually making it to the database?

Comment: Have you tried to use `update_option()` instead of `add_option()` to test? also i notice that you're trying to `get_option()` for key `form_num` but when adding the option you used `form-num` with a dash not underscore. typo?

Comment: that's a good point; I always use update_option() since it handles adding it if needed...

Comment: Ahmed Mahdi - I am using form_number because that is the name of the value/key pair in the array I pass through to ajax (called data).

Comment: I will try update_option. I have tested it. I know for sure the value is alerted out via JS on the AJAX side. I have attempted to test it on the PHP side of things and I'm not sure if it is sending a value or not... not sure why it wouldn't be.

Comment: @CC - I just tested the value. The correct value is making it to the PHP script: Object {action: "process_form", form_number: 4} | VIA this code:

  $output = "<script>console.log( 'Number: " . $num . "' );</script>";
  
  echo $output;

Comment: Scratch that - the data is NOT carrying over into PHP.

Comment: I am afraid yo misunderstand me, there's a type in the key of option in your example. i just wanted to ensure you're aware of it.

Comment: I did misunderstand, unfortunately that also didn't solve my problem. I ended up solving this using a hidden form field type and updating the data to the from via JQuery, then posting it to the server on a save action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using a hidden form field and updating the value to the hidden field via JQuery - this data was then posted to the server when the from was posted (via method="POST").